# Compute geometric transformation between pair of images

Tags: c++, opencv, transformation

I´ve got two pictures with a small transformation, because the second one was captured `1 second` later.

Now i am trying to calculate the transformation for the second picture, using the first one as a reference. First, I calculated the edge image. But how can I now compare them?

Comment: What do you mean by transformation? Are you after a [homography](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography) or you want to get the translation, scale, rotation, shear, and perspective?

Comment: I use picture a as a reference. Now my idea is, to use an matching area of picture 2. And now translate this area of picture 2 around in picture one till I find the best place. Is this possible? I found the function matchTemplate, but I´m not sure if thats the right one. Maybe I would need something like a matching factor after every try. Then I could see which position would be the best one!

Comment: Can you provide the two images?

Comment: They are just 2 edge images from a tree.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Image Registration, Alignment or sitching problem. It is a wide researched area of Computer Vision. if OpenCV 3 is available you can directly use a ready function that register two images http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/reg/doc/registration.html.

If no OpenCV 3, You should make your own. It is not that easy task. Since your images are very to close to each other, you can follow these abstract steps:

1. Detect interest points in the first image using `GFTT`.
2. Using `KLT` find the corresponding pairs in the other image.
3. Apply `RANSAC` using `cv::findHomography` on the matched paris.
4. Using the resulted homography you can wrap one of them to the other.

P.S. if you need more accuracy or better performance you should try to dig into some academic paper and find what is the state of art and try to implement it using GPU-Based Techniques.

Comment: Woulnd´t it be easier if I do it with the matchTemplate function? Trying to match the second picture to the first one, and get the biggest number from the result matrix, which will indicate the highest match?

Actually I got a number for the matching windows size for the second picture. How can i use this number? Just shrink it to that size?

Comment: No template matching is translation invariant but not rotation or scaling or skewing invariant

Comment: this topic is really hard to understand for me...  So if it says I have to use the area from the second picture with the size 40 to compare it with the whole first picture.  What area should I take from the second picture? How can one number describing a whole area in a picture?

Comment: Do not think of regular template matching. it was not created for that. and posting some samples may help finding a tricky way around

Comment: Actually I have to translate the second picture from min= -match_size/2 to max = + match_size/2. And calculate something like a score for the "matching pixel". For this I should use:
score = argmax  E(x, y) · E′(x+ i, y+ j)
And this is actually the CV_TM_CCORR method or?

After calculating alle this matching score, now I know which position is the best one. - They told me to do it that way. 
So you think I should not use templateMatching? Even with this detailed infos?

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Actually, how can i move my picture for examples 20px in x coordinate? I can not find any infos about Rect. Is this the right way?